# Count of questions with specific tag in a period

Tags: support, statistics

Does some statistic list the count of questions on Stack Overflow within an interval (month, year) having one or more specific tags?

I'm looking for a method to list the count of questions tagged with, say, *VBA-Excel* in 2017, 2018, and 2019 until today.

Comment: You can trivially query this information from [SEDE](https://data.stackexchange.com/), I know you're skilled enough in SQL to write the queries yourself. You can find the schema [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/2677/369403), make sure to use PostsWithDeleted if you want unbiased comparisons.

Comment: The "until today" part won't necessarily happen with SEDE though. It'll get you within a week though.

Comment: Thanks, @ErikA, didn't know about SEDE. Great tool.

Answer (score 3):

Yes (thanks, Eric):

[Count of questions per year from 2015 tagged 'ms-access*'](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1113573)

```sql
Select 
    Year(Posts.CreationDate), 
    Count(*) As Posts
From 
    Posts 
Where 
    PostTypeId = 1 And 
    Tags Like '%<ms-access%>%' And 
    Posts.CreationDate >= '2015-01-01'
Group By
    Year(Posts.CreationDate)
```

Answer (score 1):

Real time stats

https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=%5bms-access%5d%20is%3aq%20created%3a2019..

See here https://stackoverflow.com/help/searching

Comment: Thanks. Those options were new to me. However, my goal was to find the trend over the last five years.